# Parsing the timestamp in a html file using Jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I have to retrieve the timestamp from the html file using Jsoup. I am doing the following steps:

1.I am directly connecting to a URL using Jsoup to get the timestamp.

```
    Connection connection =Jsoup.connect(new URL(url_name)).timeout(15000); 
     Document doc = connection.get();
     Element tbody = doc.select("tbody").first();
     Elements elements=tbody.children();
     String str=elements.get(0).getElementsByClass("views-field-changed").text();
     System.out.println(str);
```

2.The contents of the URL are a href and timestamp

```
   <tbody>
      <tr class="odd views-row-first">
              <td class="views-field-phpcode">
        <a href="">12345</a>          </td>
              <td class="views-field-changed">
        2012-03-06 22:22:31          </td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
```

3.While parsing this timestamp I found that, it is not retrieving the timestamp correctly.

Using the code given in step 1, I am able to retrieve the timestamp as 2012-03-06 16:16:31 instead of 2012-03-06 22:22:31.   Note the changes in the hours and minutes.

Could you please let me know how to retrieve them?This is really urgent.

Comment: Seems to me, that Jsoup getting cached version of html page. Try to do the same from another computer.

Comment: I tried to check it and still I am getting the same. What I found out is for Hours and Minutes, it is reducing 6 hrs and showing the time.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is in the timezone. When you browsing this site with browser, it check your timezone and change the timestamp acordingly.
So, the solution is to change timezone while parsing this timestamp:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()); //or set your timezone directly
    String timestamp = format(date);
```